# Translate MySQL aggregation query to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a `comments` table that over the past year has grown considerably and I'm moving it to ElasticSearch.

The problem is that I need to adapt a query that I currently have in MySQL which returns the total number of comments for each day in the last 7 days for a given post.

Here's the MySQL query that I have now:

```
SELECT count(*) AS number, DATE(created_at) AS date 
FROM `comments` 
WHERE `post_id` = ? 
GROUP BY `date` 
ORDER BY `date` DESC 
LIMIT 7
```

My index looks like this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "post_id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "subject": {
          "analyzer": "custom_html_strip",
          "type": "text"
        },
        "body": {
          "analyzer": "custom_html_strip",
          "type": "text"
        },
        "created_at": {
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to reproduce that query for ElasticSearch? If so, how would that look like?

My ElasticSearch knowledge is kinda limited, I know that it offers `aggregation`, but I don't really know how to put it all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following query to get all the comments on a given "post_id" for the last 7 days.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "id": {
              "value": "the_post_id"
            }
          }
        },
        /*** only include this clause if you want the recent most 7 days ***/
        {
          "range": {
            "created_at": {
              "gte": "now-7d/d",
              "lt": "now/d"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "posts_per_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "created_at",
        "calendar_interval": "day",
        "order" : {"_key" : "desc"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

From the aggregation, pick up the first 7 buckets in your client application.

Comment: This returns all the posts for the last 7 days, but I need how many posts in each day of the last 7 days. I updated the original post in case this wasn't clear enough.

Comment: I have edited to give you a daily breadown. Pls mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Looks promising, but the interval for range is not correct. Check the original MySQL query and you'll see that it aggregates based on existing dates and sorts by date and takes only 7 days. So it doesn't look for `now - 7` days and `now`.

Comment: "...y have in MySQL which returns the total number of comments for each day in the last 7 days..", @antimonio.. you said "last 7 days". If you don't want to specify the days, I have edited the answer and specify both versions now.

Comment: Thanks, I think it works as it should now.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch supports sql queries as well (though they are limited)
so with a little change you can use something like this

```
GET _sql
{
  "query": """
  SELECT count(*) AS number, created_at AS date 
FROM comments
WHERE post_id = 123 
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 7
  """
}
```

You can see the corresponding query using `_sql/translate`, which will return

```
{
  "size" : 0,
  "query" : {
    "term" : {
      "post_id" : {
        "value" : 123,
        "boost" : 1.0
      }
    }
  },
  "_source" : false,
  "stored_fields" : "_none_",
  "aggregations" : {
    "groupby" : {
      "composite" : {
        "size" : 7,
        "sources" : [
          {
            "31239" : {
              "terms" : {
                "field" : "created_at",
                "missing_bucket" : true,
                "order" : "desc"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That being said, some of the stuff used in the translated query is not needed, so this will be a better native query

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "post_id": {
        "value": 123
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "unq_dates": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "created_at",
        "size": 7,
        "order": {
          "_term": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it is recommended that your time fields be regularly aggregated, so using fields written directly to a 'YYYY-MM-DD' format will improve your performance and reduce your consumption of resources

```json
{
    "query":
    {
        "filter":
        [
            {
                "term":
                {
                    "post_id":
                    {
                        "value": 1
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_source": false,
    "aggs":
    {
        "created_at":
        {
            "auto_date_histogram":
            {
                "field": "created_at",
                "buckets": 7,
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
            }
        }
    }
}
```